# window.showModalDialog for chrome

Tags: jquery

I have a simple window.showModalDialog which opens a new pop up window. It is working fine in FF and IE. But in chrome its not working. When I browsed through, I got to know that modal feature is not supported in chrome. Could any one please give me an alternative for this using jquery or any other. This is what I am trying to do. 
It should open test.html and once the child is opened, we should not be able to edit the parent window.

```
window.showModalDialog("test.html", "Edit","dialogWidth:850px; dialogHeight:650px; center:yes");
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The method exists and opens a new window, but it's not modal: it doesn't block access to the original window while it's open.

Comment: yup, it's not modal at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuert UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).